# Subsetting by [ ] returns a plurality of elements when only a single element was expected [R]. Why?

Tags: r, string, matrix, subset

Consider this [5kb data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyrvyicayrj0dqv/Billboard%20Hot100%201960.csv?dl=0) listing the 1960 Billboard Hot 100

Load the data set into [r]:

```
initFile<-read.csv("Billboard Hot100 1960.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Typing in `initFile$Title[1]` yields the following:

```
[1] Theme from A Summer Place
100 Levels: A Million to One ... Young Emotions
```

Which is about three times more information than expected - I was under the impression that only the string directly to the right of the [1] row identifier should be returned.

After further inspection it appears that `initFile$Title[1]` is not a string after all,

```
typeof(initFile$Title[1])
[1] "integer"
```

Finally, forcing the element to character returns the desired output.

```
as.character(initFile$Title[[1]])
[1] "Theme from A Summer Place"
```

Why is it that `initFile$Title[1]` doesn't return a single string element in the first place? Other languages like MATLAB seem to be more succinct in their element access routines - is there a more compact way of accessing this information that doesn't require reminding [r] that it's looking at characters?

Comment: r is reminding *you* that your data is *not* a character string

Comment: um. it's a factor. if you remove the existing, redundant parameters to `read.csv` (`header=TRUE` and `sep=","` are defaults) and add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` you'll get what you expect, but you might want to brush up on some basic R first. At least take a look at `?factor` and `?read.csv`.